# Different icon for App Store and TestFlight — same build

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm looking for a way to make our app have a different icon when it's installed through TestFlight, as opposed to the one downloaded from App Store.

I've found many questions and answers talking about how to have a different app icon for different builds (release, debug, test, etc.). But that unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.

I checked the `AppIcon` in `Assets.xcassets`. While there are different options for *Spotlight*, *Settings*, *Notification*, etc., there's no option for *TestFlight*.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, you need to create a other app, the difference between app from TestFlight or apps store, is an icon to side the name, that will appear when you install from testfligt

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. Like I was expecting already, unfortunately.